# get;set; в сущностях свойств для ЕF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Есть например сущность (*код читать не обязательно, пример из репозитория майков по е-шопу*):

```
public class CatalogItem : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public decimal Price { get; private set; }
        public string PictureUri { get; private set; }
        public int CatalogTypeId { get; private set; }
        public CatalogType CatalogType { get; private set; }
        public int CatalogBrandId { get; private set; }
        public CatalogBrand CatalogBrand { get; private set; }

        public CatalogItem(int catalogTypeId,
            int catalogBrandId,
            string description,
            string name,
            decimal price,
            string pictureUri)
        {
            CatalogTypeId = catalogTypeId;
            CatalogBrandId = catalogBrandId;
            Description = description;
            Name = name;
            Price = price;
            PictureUri = pictureUri;
        }

        public void UpdateDetails(string name, string description, decimal price)
        {
            Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty(name, nameof(name));
            Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty(description, nameof(description));
            Guard.Against.NegativeOrZero(price, nameof(price));

            Name = name;
            Description = description;
            Price = price;
        }

        public void UpdateBrand(int catalogBrandId)
        {
            Guard.Against.Zero(catalogBrandId, nameof(catalogBrandId));
            CatalogBrandId = catalogBrandId;
        }

        public void UpdateType(int catalogTypeId)
        {
            Guard.Against.Zero(catalogTypeId, nameof(catalogTypeId));
            CatalogTypeId = catalogTypeId;
        }

        public void UpdatePictureUri(string pictureName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pictureName))
            {
                PictureUri = string.Empty;
                return;
            }
            PictureUri = $"images\\products\\{pictureName}?{new DateTime().Ticks}";
        }
    }
```

**Вопрос:** Как мне правильно/лучше сделать: поля set оставить private и заполнять поля сущности через отдельные методы как в примере выше или оставить как в [документации EF](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/TimeStamp-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx):

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

То есть с public set'ами?

Comment: Лучше делать так, как сказано в документации. По идее все эти модели должны быть простыми dto чисто для сохранения данных в бд.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо, так сделаю

Comment: Guard'ы можно добавить и в сеттеры, если вы об этом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Даже ещё когда EF Core не было - уже EF 6 [поддерживал](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26768695/5752652) private сеттеры. Правда порой криво - очень много таких нестыковок я видел в статьях Аршинова на хабре, сейчас это уже достояние истории, поддержка конструкторов и приватных сеттеров сейчас намного лучше.

В документации на Core тоже есть примеры работы с private set, см. тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/constructors это вы просто не всё листали.

```
public class Blog
{
    public Blog(int id, string name, string author)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Author = author;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Author { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>();
}

public class Post
{
    public Post(int id, string title, DateTime postedOn)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
        PostedOn = postedOn;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedOn { get; private set; }

    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Поэтому, используйте вариант какой вам нравится - и так и так работает.

Единственное, вот эти отдельные методы особо не нужны сейчас, я что-то давно такого не видел в исходниках рекомендуемых приложений.

Лично мне очень нравится подход закрытых set'теров в сочетании с конструкторами - движение в сторону иммутабельных классов и функционального программирования, но это уже чистой воды вкусовщина.